# iOS 17 Password Suggestion Not Working with React Native TextInput

Tags: ios, react-native, passwords, textinput

I'm developing a React Native application, and I have a registration screen where users are asked to enter a new password and confirm it. I'm trying to leverage the iOS 17 password suggestion feature for a more user-friendly experience.

However, it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    placeholderTextColor='rgba(60, 60, 67, 0.30)'
    secureTextEntry
    placeholder={t('Registration.passwordplaceholder')}
    onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
    value={password}
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    autoCapitalize="none"
    textContentType="newPassword"
    autoComplete='new-password'
    enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
    returnKeyType='next'
/>
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    placeholderTextColor='rgba(60, 60, 67, 0.30)'
    secureTextEntry
    placeholder={t('Registration.againpasswordplaceholder')}
    onChangeText={(text) => setConfirmPassword(text)}
    value={confirmPassword}
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    autoCapitalize="none"
    textContentType="newPassword"
    autoComplete='new-password'
    enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
/>
```

With the above code, I expect iOS 17 to suggest strong passwords when users are filling out these fields, but it's not happening. Am I missing something here? Is there a specific configuration or setting I need to apply for password suggestion to work in this scenario?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.